# How do I correctly scaffold a new Docusaurus website?

Tags: npm, docusaurus

Trying to get started with a Docusaurus v2 website. Don't know much about npm or JavaScript in general, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10, `npm -v` is 6.14.8, `npx -v`is 10.2.2 and `yarn -v` is 1.22.5.

When I execute the example from the [documentation](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/installation#scaffold-project-website), I get an error:

```
$ npx @docusaurus/init init my-website classic
Too many arguments.
```

If I try without the name or template, I would expect it to prompt for them, but get another error:

```
$ npx @docusaurus/init init
Expected single character argument.
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my npm installation?

Thanks

Comment: If the examples in docs don't work, report the issue to the maintainers.

Comment: Since I don't know npm or npx at all, I wasn't sure if there something wrong my command. So you're saying, the two error messages probably come from docusaurus rather than npx ? I'll open an issue then, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I just had to user a newer `node` version. Details about the issue are [here](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/3799).
A workaround would be to use @latest as in

```
npx @docusaurus/init@latest init my-website classic
```